# What are correct permissions for /tmp ? I unintentionally set it all public recursively

Tags: permissions, chown, tmp

I have created a really really short life temporary directory that I wanted to share between some users for a few hours : `/some/path/tmp`

Unfortunately I have launched `sudo chown 777 -R /tmp` instead of `sudo chown 777 -R tmp`, so my `/tmp` file is now completely public.

Is it a security concern now that it is completely set to public? Should I change it back to more secure settings? What are the correct permissions for `/tmp`?

Comment: Beware that I forgot something important in my initial answer: the X11 socket needs to be publicly accessible, otherwise you won't be able to start new GUI applications. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Was it `chown` or `chmod`?

Comment: @Melebius I am a bit puzzled by your question: I did not mention `chmod`. chown (like ch - own), is about ownership of files, which user owns a file. chmod (like ch - modifify) is more about who can execute, or write inside, or read the content of a file.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Yes, that’s what confused me. You can use `chown 777` which sets the ownership of a file to the user with the ID 777. However, all the answers, including the accepted one, work with `chmod`. Since all of them set the permission to the same value for all the users (owner, group, others), most effects of the file ownership become irrelevant. However, the correct command to rectify the result of `sudo chown 777 -R /tmp` should be `sudo chown root -R /tmp`.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The normal settings for `/tmp` are 1777, which `ls` shows as `drwxrwxrwt`. That is: wide open, except that only the owner of a file can remove it (that's what this extra `t` bit means for a directory).

The problem with a `/tmp` with mode 777 is that another user could remove a file that you've created and substitute the content of their choice.

If your `/tmp` is a tmpfs filesystem, a reboot will restore everything. Otherwise, run `chmod 1777 /tmp`.

Additionally, a lot of files in `/tmp` need to be private. However, at least one directory critically needs to be world-readable: `/tmp/.X11-unix`, and possibly some other similar directories (`/tmp/.XIM-unix`, etc.). The following command should mostly set things right:

```bash
chmod 1777 /tmp
find /tmp \
     -mindepth 1 \
     -name '.*-unix' -exec chmod 1777 {} + -prune -o \
     -exec chmod go-rwx {} +
```

I.e. make all files and directories private (remove all permissions for group and other), but make the X11 sockets accessible to all. Access control on these sockets is enforced by the server, not by the file permissions. There may be other sockets that need to be publicly available. Run `find /tmp -type s -user 0` to discover root-owned sockets which you may need to make world-accessible. There may be sockets owned by other system users as well (e.g. to communicate with a system bus); explore with `find /tmp -type s ! -user $UID` (where `$UID` is your user ID).

Comment: could you explain the second chmod more?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski `go-rwx`: no permissions for group and others. This sets the permissions to `rwx------` (except that files that were created since the `chmod` may end up with fewer permissions, e.g. `rw-------`). In other words, the files will be accessible only by their owner. `/tmp/.[!.]*` is to include dot files, which commonly exist in `/tmp`.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski:  chmod -go-rwx  : set "rwx" rights to Owner and Group.  r=read, w=write, x=execute(for file) or enter/traverse(for directory).   777 = rwxrwxrwx (the right part can be seen as : "set 'r' set 'w' set 'x', set 'r' set 'w' set 'x', set 'r' set 'w' set 'x'" , which in binary is represented as "111111111" (1 to set, 0 to unset) . And "111111111" in binary is represented in octal as "777" (octal = groups of 3 bits, each group having value 0 to 7). if "rwxr-xr--" it would be "111101100" which in octal is "754"

Comment: The +t is referred to as the sticky bit.  That's what keep anyone other than the owner from being able to remove files, even though the permissions are 777 otherwise.  The sticky bit was originally to get the kernel to leave commonly programs in memory when they exited so they wouldn't have to be fetched from disk when next run.  We're talking PDP11 days....

Comment: I'm running `chmod -R go-rwx /tmp/* /tmp/.[!.]*` on Ubuntu 16.04 and getting an error: `-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Argument list too long`

Comment: @GabrielFair I replaced the command using wildcards by one using find which won't run into that problem.

Comment: wouldnt this be enough? (if you are able to reboot the server) `chmod 1777 /tmp; reboot`

Comment: also check `/var/tmp` the same way, maybe you have the same error there

Comment: Should I also do `chmod 1777 -R /tmp` for reaching out to subfolders I have created?

Comment: @alper No, do not do that. 1777 is for `/tmp` itself, which is writable by everybody. Almost all directories in `/tmp` should only be readable and writable by their owner.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' "If your `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` filesystem, a reboot will restore everything. ***Otherwise, run `chmod 1777 /tmp`***." Two question arise: 1. how to know whether `/tmp` is `tmpfs` filesystem or not? 2. what do you want to tell us by ***"Otherwise, run `chmod 1777 /tmp`"***, could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: @John To see if `/tmp` is a tmpfs filesystem, run `df /tmp` and see whether it's something like `/dev/… … … … … /` (part of the root filesystem) or `tmpfs … … … … /tmp` (a separate tmpfs filesystem). As for `chmod 1777 /tmp`, not sure what to add. It's the command to set `/tmp` to the permissions it should have.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Why should invoke `run chmod 1777 /tmp` when `/tmp` is not tmpfs filesystem?

Comment: @John This is an answer to the question “What are correct permissions for /tmp ?”

Answer (score 17):

`/tmp` and `/var/tmp` should have read, write and execute rights for all; but you'd usually would also add the sticky-bit (`o+t`), to prevent users from removing files/directories belonging to other users.  So `chmod a=rwx,o+t /tmp` should work.

As for changing permissions recursively...  As long as the owner/group remains as it is for the files and directories, it shouldn't be that much of a problem.  But you could perhaps change the permission of everything under `/tmp` (not /tmp itself) to ensure users' privacy, by removing the `rx` rights of others and perhaps the group.

Find is a good way of doing this.  As root, do:

```
cd /tmp
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,go= {} \;   # (or u=rw,g=r,o= {})
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,go= {} \;  # (or u=rwx,g=rx,o= {})
```

Comment: On a typical desktop system, you'd better make `/tmp/.X11-unix/*` world-readable as well, or you won't be able to start X applications any more.

Comment: `chmod a=rwX,o+t /tmp -R` should do the `find` magic.

Comment: @dhill, your command ends up with strange permissions: `-rw-rw-rwT` those are not the original permissions

Answer (score 3):

```
[root@Niflheim tmp]# ls -alF .
total 1632
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root    4096 Apr  7 04:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    4096 Apr  2 21:02 ../
[root@Niflheim tmp]# stat -c '%A %a %n' .
drwxrwxrwt 1777 .
```

From a CentOS 5.9 machine.