# fakeroot cdebootstrap: Failed to unshare: Operation not permitted

Tags: debootstrap, fakeroot

On Debian, when running:

```
$ fakeroot cdebootstrap stable /tmp/foo
```

cdebootstrap downloads the packages, but when it has to extract them, I get this error:

```
E: Failed to unshare: Operation not permitted
```

How can I run cdebootstrap as non-root?

This part in unshare's manual seems relevant, but am not sure how:

```
EPERM (since Linux 3.9)
              CLONE_NEWUSER was specified in flags and the caller is in a
              chroot environment (i.e., the caller's root directory does not
              match the root directory of the mount namespace in which it
              resides).
```

Comment: Can you list the packages, and their associated permissions here: `ls -al /tmp/foo`?

Comment: Yes, they're in `/tmp/foo/var/cache/bootstrap/`, and their permissions are set to 644 to my user.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo fakeroot`  It's the fakeroot that isn't permissioned right...?

Comment: @eyoung100 I'm not sure I understand? `sudo fakeroot` does work.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Your issue has to do with permission inheritance.  `cdbootstrap` will inherit the permissions of `fakeroot`, which can be elevated via `sudo`. Issue:

`sudo fakeroot cdbootstrap /tmp/foo`

If the above command succeeds, permissions on `/tmp` are the issue.  See [What are common rights for /tmp ? I unintentionally set it all public recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-common-rights-for-tmp-i-unintentionnally-set-it-all-public-recursive), for what the default permissions should be.  Generally, writing anything into `/tmp` that wasn't put there by an application is a bad idea, and `fakeroot` has its own issues.  From the man page:

> ### LIMITATIONS
>
> #### Library versions
>
> Every command executed within fakeroot needs to be linked to the
> same version of the C library as fakeroot itself.
>
> #### `open()`/`create()`
>
> `fakeroot`  doesn't  wrap `open()`, `create()`, etc. So, if user `joost`      does either
>
> ```
>   touch foo
>   fakeroot
>   ls -al foo
> ```
>
> or the other way around,
>
> ```
>   fakeroot
>   touch foo
>   ls -al foo
> ```
>
> `fakeroot` has no way of knowing that in the first case, the owner
> of  `foo`  really  should be `joost` while the second case it should
> have been `root`.  For the Debian packaging, defaulting to  giving
> all "unknown" files uid=gid=0, is always OK. The real way around
> this is to wrap `open()` and  `create()`,  but  that  creates  other
> problems, as demonstrated by the `libtricks` package. This package
> wrapped many more functions, and tried to do  a  lot  more  than
> `fakeroot` .  It turned out that a minor upgrade of libc (from one
> where the `stat()` function didn't use `open()` to one with a `stat()`
> function that did (in some cases) use `open()`), would cause
> unexplainable segfaults  (that  is,  the  libc6  `stat()`  called  the
> wrapped  `open()`,  which  would then call the libc6 `stat()`, etc).
> Fixing them wasn't all that easy, but once fixed, it was just  a
> matter  of  time  before another function started to use `open()`,
> never mind trying to port it to a  different  operating  system.
> Thus  I decided to keep the number of functions wrapped by `fakeroot`
> as small as possible, to limit the  likelihood  of  'collisions'.

> ### BUGS
>
> It doesn't wrap `open()`. This isn't bad by itself, but if a program
> does    `open("file", O_WRONLY, 000)`, writes to file "file", closes it,
> and then    again tries to open to read the file, then that open
> fails, as the mode    of the file will be 000. The bug is that if root
> does the same,  `open()`    will succeed, as the file permissions aren't
> checked at all for root. I    choose not to wrap `open()`, as `open()` is
> used by many other functions in    libc  (also  those  that  are
> already wrapped), thus creating loops (or    possible future loops,
> when the implementation of  various  libc  functions slightly
> change).

---

### Better Solution

Instead of using privilege escalation to achieve what you're trying to do consider using a proper `chroot`, as outlined in the [DebootstrapChroot Documentation for Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot), or the [Official Debian Documentation for DebBootStrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap).

Comment: I don't want to use `sudo`. I want to have a user-space chroot, hence my reason to use `fakeroot` in the first place. It's also not an issue with `/tmp/`, since it has the same issue with a folder in `$HOME`.

Comment: Read the Documentation I provided under Better Solution and install the DebBootstrap in userspace, Fakeroot will not work using the method you're trying to use it for, because of the Limitations in the Limitation Section above.  Fakeroot is mainly used to modify config files, and build debian packages.  It cannot emulate a full fleged `chroot`

Answer (score 0):

maybe /tmp is the issue. try

$fakeroot cdebootstrap stable $HOME/somedir

Comment: No, it's not working either, same error.